# Bounding error when iterating a function

Tags: numerical-methods, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, analytic-number-theory

If I am iterating some function $f$ that goes to infinity as x goes to infinity with error $o(g(x))$, for example, is there anyway to bound the error? To be more specific, if I have some sequence $a_n, a_1=1, a_{n+1}=f(a_n)+o(g(a_n))$, is there something we can say about how well $f^{k-n}(a_n)$? approximates $a_k$?

$f^{k-n}$ is f itterated $k-n$ times.

More clarification: If a sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3,...$ is modeled by $f(1), f(f(1)), f(f(f(1))),...$, what can say about the behavior of the sequence $a_1-f(1), a_2-f(f(1)),...$? Can we say that this sequence is o(some function that depends on g)?

Comment: You may want to add other tags. Perhaps, recurrence relations or numerical analysis.

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what $f^{k-n}(a_n)
$ means. Not a power, I suppose.

Comment: I think that the correct formula is $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)=a_n+o(g(a_n))$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla No, $f(a_n)$ approximates $a_{n+1}$

Comment: If you assume $f$ is Lipschitz probably you will get something.

Answer (score 3):

This is supposed to be a comment but I can't fit it into the comment box.

Even if you have $f(x) = h(x)$ for all $x > $ some $M$ and $|f(x)-h(x)| \ll 1$ over $[0,M]$, the two sequences $(x_n)$, $(y_n)$ defined by 
$$
x_n = f^{\circ (n-1)}(1) = \begin{cases}1, &n = 1\\ f(x_{n-1}), & n > 1\end{cases}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
y_n = h^{\circ (n-1)}(1) = \begin{cases}1, &n = 1\\ h(y_{n-1}), & n > 1\end{cases}
$$
can have very different behavior. For a concrete example, let $\epsilon$ be a small number, say $\epsilon = 0.001$ and define

$$f(x) = x(2-\cos(2\pi x))+1
\quad\text{ and }\quad
h(x) = f(x) + \begin{cases} \epsilon x(2-x),& x < 2\\0, &x \ge 2\end{cases}
$$
It is easy to check $x_n = f^{\circ (n-1)}(1) = n$ and yet $y_n = h^{\circ(n-1)}(1)$ 
blows up non-linearly!
$$\begin{array}{|r:r|}
\hline
n & y_n\\
\hline
1 & 1.0000000000\\
2 & 2.0010000000\\
3 & 3.0010394980\\
4 & 4.0011035079\\
5 & 5.0011996822\\
10 & 10.0035221944\\
15 & 17.5415709482\\
20 & 463.3074993684\\
25 & 32972.6418308000\\
30 & 2651994.7780103278\\
35 & 15400024.3406490520\\
40 & 857042166.1092528100\\
45 & 44608271060.7540660000\\
50 & 713883229051.1130400000\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: How does quickly $y_n-x_n$ blow up? Even if nothing can be said in general, I don't even know how one would determine the error term.

Comment: @vukov Numerically, for this particular example using data for $n$ upto $500$, $y_n \sim O( e^{\alpha n} )$ with $\alpha \sim 0.63$. This number is pretty close to the integral $\int_0^1 \log(2-cos(2\pi x))dx \sim 0.623811$. This suggest once $a_n$ moves away from $n$ ( which sort of like an unstable fixed point in a dynamical system ), $a_n - n$ starts to wander randomly and eventually pickup the "average" growth inherent in the $f(x)$.

Comment: Is there a rigorous way to show this?

Comment: @vukov This is only an example, it is pointless to prove anything.